# Change Dropdown to checkbox in View

Tags: views, 8

I'm using

```
Content: Translation language (exposed)
```

in my code, And I Have two Options
- autocomplete
- dropdown

I'd like to have Checkbox, How Can I enable it?

[image]

I'm using Drupal 8

Comment: bef for drupal 7 may the logic will help you out

Answer (score 3):

Not sure where you're trying to do this, but if it's a node edit form, you can just change the widget to "Check boxes/radio buttons" on Manage Form Display (`admin/structure/types/manage/<content_type>/form-display`). Make sure the Options module is installed.

For an exposed filter in a View, say, you can use a `hook_form_alter` to change the `#type` to whatever you want; e.g.:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['field_your_field']['#type'] = 'checkboxes';

  // If there's no user input (code not shown), rebuild the form.
  $form_state->setRebuild();
}
```

Only makes sense if `#multiple` is set to `TRUE` of course.

UPDATE: Added the call to `setRebuild()`.

Answer (score 1):

On Drupal 8.7.8 it is nearly the same.

Edit your themes/YOURTHEME/YOURTHEME.theme file and add

```
function YOURTHEME_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['field_your_field']['#type'] = 'checkboxes';
}
```

The setRebuild() call breaks the functionality on my system.

field_your_field is the system name of the field you want to change, either find it by using browser development tools or the field config of your respective content type.